# Null pointer exception json parser

Tags: android, json

This is what i have tried,

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    jsonObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://shoppersays.com/mypromocheck/api/v1/users?&username=avinash&password=avinash2");
    try {
        String Authen_status = jsonObject.getString("Authen_status");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Authen_status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get a `NullPointerException`. I ran this on android 2.2, it ran successfully, then tried on 4.0, its giving null pointer exception in `getstring()` line, please help!!

Edit 1:

Log

```
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start              activity ComponentInfo{com.viralmo.readjson/com.viralmo.readjson.ReadJson}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at com.viralmo.readjson.ReadJson.onCreate(ReadJson.java:23)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
03-28 23:46:52.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1694):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Is this running in a background thread?

Comment: @Raghav, nope this is the main thread, on 2.2 no issues, when run on 4.0 this error, i also added if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
              } in json parser but no use!

Answer (score 0):

Throw that into doInBackground() in an AsyncTask().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

and a tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#asynctask

Comment: hi Bill Mote, thanks for the input, but how do you do that?? call doinBackground() and pass here?? can you please provide an example!

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @RaghavSood commented..androdi 3.x or higher version , doesn't allow network operations on the UI thread, but lower version will allow.

So When you are trying to perform network operation, on 3.x above versions you'll get NetworkOnMainThread Exception.

```
 jsonObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://shoppersays.com/mypromocheck/api/v1/users?&username=avinash&password=avinash2");
```

Here you `jsonObject` will be null when you failed to get the response from service. So operation on jsonObject which is null will throw `NullPointerException`

> How to overcome it?

Use separate thread or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform long running operations

Comment: @downvoter should have a valid reason downvote. If you find any should comment.. It seems either you don't know technology or you may downvote intentionally